# Bind Query Results To Combo Box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

This is what I have, and it is not producing any errors, but the combo box is not displaying the results  of my SQL statement either?

This doesn't produce any error, but my combo box gets populated with System.Data.DataRowView

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string sql = null;
string connectionString = "";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
sql = "";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
DataTable 1234 = new DataTable();
da.Fill(1234);
combobox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
combobox1.ValueMember = "FirstName";
combobox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet ds never gets added to.  Your SqlDataAdapter fills DataTable 1234.  Change your code to do this:

combobox1.DataSource = 1234;

Or have you SqlDataAdapter File ds.

Comment: There is no need to use DataSet as you are not using it any where just DataTable is sufficient for your query.